# RabbitMq Node js Microservice

Tags: node.js, npm, rabbitmq

why I am not able to install amqp with 16+ node version. I am trying to installing amqp for microservices. I am started learn microservices with nodejs.
when i am creating a mini app in node js.it gives me error.
can any body know good resources of node js microservices

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=12' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.2', npm: '8.1.2' }
```

when i am created new project of with npm init and now try to install amqplib it gets installed.i think its a problem with nest js

Comment: I cant understand what your installation problem is because of lack of info in your question but maybe you can try `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: @OnurkanBakırcı I am not able to install amqplib why?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you have node16?

```
node --version
```

First clean up a bit.

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules // linux or gitbash
rm package-lock.json
```

remove the entry of the ampq entries in the package.json -> dependencys

```
npm i
npm i amqplib
```